# Visual Studio 2013 tries to configure itself after adding a VB6 addon

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have a new machine. I installed VS 2013 Community Edition. Then I installed VB6. Both went well and work well. But as soon as I add the addon "VB6MouseWheel.EXE" to VB6, A Visual Studio 2013 dialog box appears and says to please wait while Windows configures Visual Studio 2013 Professional. That process loops through itself several times before VB6 crashes. If I disable the addon, VB6 works fine. I have the same arrangement on another machine so I know they can work together.

Has anyone else run into this?

UPDATE: 
I reformatted and installed VB6 first as per xxbbcc, and ran VB6 with the addon just fine. But then I installed VS2013 and the problem came back. Shoot.

Comment: I haven't run into this so I can't tell what's wrong but with earlier VS versions, you had to install them in correct version order (VB6 / VS6 first, configure it) and then VS 2013. Don't know if this was a fact or just anecdotal

Comment: @xxbbcc  Hmmm I did install VS2013 first...

Comment: Sorry, I had to walk away before I could finish typing up my comment - I never had issues when I followed that "rule" but I experienced various issues when I didn't. As I said, I don't know if it used to be a hard requirement but VS 6 is a ~15 year old version, so it may be worth trying the other order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4b0fd38-f4f9-41ea-bd8d-834203a175d2/building-visual-studio-2010-project-triggers-please-wait-while-windows-configures-visual-studio?forum=vssetup&prof=required). I needed to add the folder C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC\

Answer (score 0):

only way I fixed this was by recompiling VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.vbp myself, I think it comes bundled with the dll, then I unregistered VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll and registered my newly compiled dll and it somehow then worked